# Procedure or function has too many arguments specified in my stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql

I have this stored procedure and when I call from my c# code, I get the error and I don't know what is the problem.

Stored procedure

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[modProducto]    

Store Procedure    
@id integer,    
@descripcion varchar(100),    
@tipoproducto integer,  
@existencia integer,  
@precio money  
AS  
 update producto  
set descripcion = @descripcion, idtipoproducto = @tipoproducto, existencia = @existencia, precio = @precio  
where idproducto = @id  
select 'Producto modificado correctamente'
```

C# Code

```
MessageBox.Show(cx.ejecutarOtro("modProducto " +    
                                txtProducto.Text + ",'" +  
                                txtDescripcion.Text + "'," +  
                                (comboProducto.SelectedIndex + 1) + "," +  
                                numericUpDownExistencia.Text + "," +  
                                txtPrecioProducto.Text  
                               ));
```

- `cx.ejecutarotro` is an method that execute the SQL query.
- `txtProducto`, `txtDescripcion` and `txtPrecioProducto` are textboxes.
- `Numericupdownexistencia` is a `NumericUpDown` box.
- `comboProducto` is a dropdown list.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you know something about sql injection?

Comment: Ooh, ouch. Yes, if that is how you normally do data access, you need to stop that real quick. Parameters. That'll solve the problem **and** stop someone on the Internet deleting your database after stealing all your data. Wins all around.

Comment: Can you show me where to learn about the parameters? im new at this and is a small university project. Thank you!.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is probably i18n formatting of numbers - commas vs periods. The answer is: parse the inputs properly, and use parameters. Never. Never. Never concatenate user input into SQL. Did I mention never?

Comment: After some testing, is the decimal of the txtPrecioProducto, when i parse this into int, the problem was "solved" but i need it as decimal :s

Comment: @manumotate seriously: ***use parameters***. We're not kidding: what you have currently is actively dangerous

Comment: yeah, im reading about the parameters, i will change the code in my program. thanks you :).